# Can I set authorization cookies obtained from cURL?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authorization

is that possible, to authorize within example.com login form with cURL, and detect the cookies and set them to user?

My goal is to authorize users ( with their pre-set credentials) to another site automatically,so trying to avoid manual user& password entry step ( or hidden html form submission).

Comment: Yes there is no ip checking is there (in case your curl machine is different that that of users machine)  but how will to transfer that cookie to user's web browser?

Comment: @Viney very good catch about IP's. however, lets say, IP doesnt matter. then?

Comment: Sure it's possible if there is no ip checking and no browsers user-agent checking.I mean if cookies are the sole way to identify a client for the server.

Comment: @Viney yes,   that's what i wanted to know PHP code to acheive that.  thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
curl -v ...
```

to get your cookies - you can see them in the response header. Then you can add the cookie in curl as follows:

```
--cookie "cookieName=cookieValue"
```

Comment: thanks! and how to add multiple cookies? using `--cookie "first=smth&second=smth"` ?